# Pass array by ajax with MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems to passa an Javascript array by ajax to my application. The ajax call is executing my server-side method but the parameter is null, and, even before my method finish processing, ajax throws error (execute its error function).

This is my ajax call:

```
<script>
    var permissoesUsuario = Array();
    $(function () {
        //funcao de envio das permissoes
        $('#btnSalvar').click(function () {
            //desabilita o botao de salvar
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            $.each($('input[name="chkPermissao"]:checked'), function () {
                permissoesUsuario.push({
                    IdEmpresa: $(this).attr('data-empresa'),
                    IdPermissao: $(this).attr('data-permissao')
                });
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '@(Url.Content("~/Funcionario/Permissoes"))',
                data: JSON.stringify(permissoesUsuario),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    permissoesUsuario = Array();
                    if (response == '') {
                        window.location = '@(Url.Content("~/Funcionario"))';
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('Erro');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

And my server-side method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Permissoes(IList<PermissaoAcessoInputModel> permInput)
{
     //Do something
}
```

My permInput variable is null..

This is my PermissaoAcessoInputModel Class:

```
public class PermissaoAcessoInputModel
{
    public virtual int IdPermissao { get; set; }

    public virtual ulong? IdEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify if the data is actually being sent by javascript or not? You can see this from browser console > network > request. Or if you don't like to use browser console then you can use Third party tool like fiddler.

Comment: Yes, its posting the JSON: [{"IdEmpresa":"0","IdPermissao":"8"},{"IdEmpresa":"0","IdPermissao":"33"}]

Comment: Can you try sending your data as {"permInput": JSON.stringify(permissoesUsuario)}

Comment: I already tried this way, didn't work too, I still get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
traditional: true
```

In your AJAX options?

ex

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Funcionario/Permissoes")',
            data: JSON.stringify(permissoesUsuario),
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                permissoesUsuario = Array();
                if (response == '') {
                    window.location = '@Url.Content("~/Funcionario")';
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('Erro');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried `traditional: true` too.. Still getting error, I checked the console, Browser just says that the error occurred in this line, inside jQuery file: `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );` I checked s.HasContent and its `true` and s.data is my JSON `[{"IdEmpresa":"0","IdPermissao":"8"},{"IdEmpresa":"0","IdPermissao":"33"}] `

Comment: I would try to see more information from the error by using something like `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    alert("error:" + xhr.status + ' - > ' + xhr.responseText);
                }`

Comment: It shows `error:0 - >`
Its driving me crazy, I dont know what else to try!

Comment: I found the problem.. The button I was using was with `type=submit` but its supposed to be `type=button`!

Comment: Ah good news. You should definitely consider downloading fiddler. With it you can see the contents of your requests/responses, and you can look at any JSON objects being passed around. It can do much more I'm sure but for these reasons alone it's worth having.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew fiddler, I downloaded and liked it! I was just using Firebug for FireFox. Thank you for the tip!